# complex analysis poles and residues

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory

I am trying to understand a lemma on the (end of the first page - second page) on this link: http://pollack.uga.edu/infprimes-final.pdf

> [image]

Basically, they end up with $$\sum_{d \geq 1}f(d) \frac{z^d}{1-z^d}$$
*note that when I doing this lemma, I have $f(d)$ rather than $\check{f}(d)$ but I don't think it makes a difference to my question. Basically, how can they conclude that there exists poles at $z = e^{(2\pi i)/2}$.

I know that if a function $f(z) = \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is in its reduced form, then it will have a pole at every zero of $Q(z)$ but I get lost in their lemma.

Comment: If $f$ is of finite support and $D$ is the largest integer for which $f(D)$ is nonzero, then we actually end up with $\sum_{1\le d\le D} f(d)\frac{z^d}{1-z^d}.$ It is possible to check that for $d<D$, $z=e^{2\pi i/D}$ is not a root of $1-z^d$ and hence all of the summands except for the last are defined, but the last summand $f(D)\frac{z^D}{1-z^D}$ will of course have a pole there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that $z \mapsto \frac{z^k}{1-z^k}$ has a pole at $z$ iff $z^k =1$, and $z^k=1$ iff $z = e^{2 \pi i \frac{m}{k}}$.

The expression is of the form $z \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^D \phi_n \frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$, where $\phi_D \ne 0$. Then for $1 \le n\le D$, we have $(1-e^{2 \pi i \frac{n}{D}}) = 0$ iff $n=D$. In particular, $z \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{D-1} \phi_n \frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$ is analytic at $z=e^{2 \pi i \frac{1}{D}}$. Hence the expression has a pole at $z=e^{2 \pi i \frac{1}{D}}$.

Comment: Is there a reason why the author does the "max" thing. ie what is the reasoning behind showing that $|F(z)| \leq A\frac{.}{.}$

Comment: So the summation can be rearranged. Essentially, if a series is absolutely summable, you can rearrange the summation in any way.

Comment: Could you explain your last line. why is it analytic at $z = e^{2\pi i 1/d}$

Comment: Notice the upper limit is $D-1$ in the last summation. The functions $z \mapsto \frac{1}{1-z^n}$ are analytic at $z = e^{2\pi i 1/d}$ because $z^n \neq 1$ for $n=1,...,D-1$. Does that explain it?

Comment: Okay and last question. You say $z^k = 1$ iff $z = e^{2\pi i \frac{m}{k}}$ what is m in this case?

Comment: $m$ is any integer. (But only $m=0,...,k-1$ are needed since $e^{2 \pi i l} = 1$ for any integer $l$).

Comment: Okay so you have that for all $n < D$ the denominator can not be zero. What if $n$ is a multiple of 2? wouldnt that make the denominator zero?

Comment: I'm not sure what $n$ being even has to do with it. But to answer your question, if $n = 1,...,D-1$, then $z \mapsto \frac{1}{1-z^n}$ is analytic at $z = e^{2\pi i 1/d}$.

Comment: Okay, I am pretty confused about it. I will read it over and over. thanks for your help.

Comment: This doesn't help, but the whole key to that particular argument is understanding the zeros of $1-z^n$. For each $n>1$, $1-z^n$ has a zero that is not a zero of the lower powers.